# php append within a header

Tags: php

How would you add a variable within quotations marks? Here's what I'm trying to do but it's not working.

```
header("Location: mainpage.php?note=".$note_title);
```

Also is there a way to indent blocks of code on Stack Overflow without having to do four spaces on each individual line?

Comment: That should work (as long as `$note_title` is defined and contains what you want it to contain). Whats the problem? Your second question: No.

Comment: To indent: select you code ond press Ctrl+K

Comment: You can highlight a block of code with your mouse and then click the `{}`, it will add the spaces automatically for you.

Comment: Indent however you like or not at all then highlight the code block and click on the `{}` button and it will indent for a code block for you.

Comment: write `exit()` after `header()`

Comment: Oh you guys are right, I forgot to carry a POST value. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like:

```
header("Location: mainpage.php?note=$note_title");
```

This is the standard way.  If it is not working the problem is not with the code you posted.

As for the second part, you can use tabs, but not effectively in a browser window usually.

Comment: I don't know if there's a "standard way", that's just another way of doing something that should work in the example in the question.

Comment: Fair enough.  "A" standard way then.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. , as KingCrunch said.

```
<?php
$note_title="24";
header("Location: mainpage.php?note=".$note_title);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotes to your value like that:

```
$note_title = '"your_value"';
```

Comment: I think you're thinking that his problem is with breaks in the `$note_title` text.  It may be, but with the information given I don't think it's reasonable to assume.